# Create a 3D matrix from a generator of 2D matrices

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am using `pandas` to read a number of `.csv` files. Each file will produce a *3x5* dataframe.

```
dtx = (pd.read_csv(f).values for f in get_filelist(datadirectory))
```

I want to combine all the data from the various files in order to create a 3 dimensional array (if I have 10 files then I want to end up with an array of shape: *10x3x5*)

I could create an empty python list and append all the arrays found in `dtx` using a for loop, but I would like a more pythonic solution. I have tried

```
np.concatenate([tf for tf in dtx])
```

without having the desired effect. How can I concatenate all of the data I read from my `.csv` files into a big 3D array?

Comment: Try `dtx = np.stack([pd.read_csv(f).values for f in get_filelist(datadirectory)], axis=0)`.

Comment: @jdehesa it seems to be working, I am not sure which of the two solutions is better but I think you should add it as an answer so I can upvote it and others can see too.

Comment: `np.stack` does what the accepted answer does - you can read its code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new dimension to the arrays and concatenate them:

```
dtx = (pd.read_csv(f).values for f in get_filelist(datadirectory))
np.concatenate([tf[np.newaxis] for tf in dtx], axis=0)
```

Example:

```
np.concatenate([tf[np.newaxis] for tf in (np.arange(4).reshape((2,2)) for i in range(3))], axis=0)
>> array([[[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[0, 1],
        [2, 3]],

       [[0, 1],
        [2, 3]]])
```